# C# datetimepicker if equals today then tick checkbox, else not checked/uncheck

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement, datetimepicker

I am trying to have a check box (`notTodayCheckBox`) that if the datetimepicker (`DateTimePicker`) has a selection of today it isn't checked, if the selection is not today it is checked.

My current code ticks the box if the date selected isn't today, but if I change it back to today the box doesn't uncheck.

Current Code:

```
private void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DateTime check;
     if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker.Text, out check) && check != DateTime.Now)
     {
          notTodayCheckBox.Checked = true;
     }
     else if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker.Text, out check) && check == DateTime.Now)
     {
          notTodayCheckBox.Checked = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are checking with datetime (DateTIme.Now) with date thats why it remain false all the time.

Comment: Hi, you have to compare the dates with DateTime.Compare(check, DateTime.Now). Also it´s better to parse the Datetimpicker.text only once. Another problem is that the datetime also contains the minutes, seconds and so on. So the dates are only the same if all components are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` has a time element into it and maybe your datepicker is set on a different time, even a second will render them not equal.

if you are just after the date without caring for the time.

Convert `check` and `DateTime.Now` to `ShortDateString()`

it will treat both as `string` with format `mm/dd/yyyy`

`check.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()`

or as per *René Vogt*

`check.Date == DateTime.Today` or `DateTime.Now.Date`
both will return `DateTime` with time set to `12:00:00AM`

Comment: or simply use `check.Date == DateTime.Today`.

Comment: @RenéVogt yes, forgot about that, may I add it on my answer? or you could add yours and ill upvote it

Comment: you can have it :)